# Which test and how should I apply- comparing signal to noise

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

Imagine two data sets, one is a measurement of a particular analyte in a sample and the other is used to blank the instrument.  There will be some noise from the instrument when I measure [blank solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_(solution)) causing variance in the value.  When I measure the sample, there could be a couple different sources of variance.

I want to see if an analyte is under a certain constant limit, let's say `L`, perhaps because the analyte has known toxicity above that level.  The blank deals with the fact there is already some analyte present and I want to track the amount added by my sample.  The data sets are small so I want to force a check that ensures I'm 95% confident that the Sample is less than the Limit.

[image]

`Blank: {50, 52, 63}`

`Sample: {74, 71}`

In this case, though, I feel I should apply a one tailed test of some sort.  Also, the two sets are of unequal variance and sample sizes.  This pointed me towards a Welches' T Test where I can calculate the degrees of freedom using the  Welch–Satterthwaite equation.  Though I'm not sure how to fully apply the test.  Once I have the P value for my degrees of freedom and confidence level (let's say 95%), how do I fully calculate my t statistic for comparison?

Comment: Note that hypotheses are in terms of underlying (unobserved, *population*) quantities, not sample quantities. An hypothesis might be something like $\mu_s-\mu_b\leq \ell$ vs $\mu_s-\mu_b> \ell$ (equality would be in the null because  otherwise - for example - imagine what happens in the limit as $n\to\infty$ and the difference goes to $\ell$; you end up with the power going to $\alpha$ under the alternative). Alternatively you might perhaps be looking for a form of *noninferiority test*.

Comment: With the differing variances, is the spread related to the mean?

Comment: Sorry - need to clarify -- spread (as in my question) is proportional to standard deviation rather than variance. Is it really the variance or the standard deviation that you're saying is "proportional to the signal"?

Comment: The error in the instrument measurement is proportional to the measurement value.  i.e. Instrument accuracy is 1% of signal (thus the blank has a lower variance than the sample for this particular source of electronic noise)
Sorry Glen for being obtuse in this matter, and I don't know I can adequately answer this question.
Naively, if the variance is the square of the standard deviation, wouldn't they both be dependent upon the same things?   oi, I've come for answers, and only feel dumber.

Comment: Yes, they both depend on the same thing but they can't both be proportional to it; it will make a difference which it is. In the case where standard deviation is proportional to mean, you might be better off considering working on the log-scale, or possibly modelling via a glm which has that variance specification and testing your hypothesis that way.

Comment: @Glen_b there is always a chance that I'm not even near on the right track... grief I wished hardcore stats were required for chemists back when I was in school...